# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/jpeg-xl/lib/libjxl.0.7.dylib

Tags: dyld

I've upgraded my macbook to Big Sur 11.7.8 and now running php 8.0 (or 8.1, 8.2) in the terminal fails with this error.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/jpeg-xl/lib/libjxl.0.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/libavif/lib/libavif.15.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I've tried removing and reinstalling with brew, brew upgrade and cleanup but so far no luck. I only get the same error during the install process. Any ideas please?

Thanks

Comment: I've fixed it. I reinstalled the command line tools,  re-installed jpeg-xl (it was already there) and re-installed php and that seems to have sorted it.

Comment: Do you mean you did "brew reinstall ffmpeg" by command line tools?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into same issue when upgrading to MacOS Big Sur 11.7.8. The solution is to reinstall jpeg-xl.

If you use brew, then

```bash
brew install jpeg-xl
```

Would do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after installing macOS Sonoma.
Try to reinstall gd:

```
brew reinstall gd
```

Comment: This command works for me. Thanks!